# Dynamics CRM Online 2016 - Daemon / Server application Azure AD authentication error to Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, crm, microsoft-dynamics, azure-active-directory

I am building a C# windows service that needs to connect to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web API. 
I am using the example code from github ["A .NET 4.5 daemon application that uses a certificate to authenticate with Azure AD and get OAuth 2.0 access tokens, Github"](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential).

I am able to retrieve an access token from AAD, however, when I call the Dynamics CRM resource i get the following error:

> HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied
>
> StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1,
>
> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error=invalid_token, error_description=Error during token validation!,

I have also tried using client id and client key, but I get the same error.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: please see the answer to my similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454539/using-adal-c-sharp-as-confidential-user-daemon-server-server-to-server-401-u